# Possible set theoretic hazzard with this definition?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I don't know much about ZFC set theory, other than that it exist, and my thinking of set theory more or less corresponds to "naive set theory".

However, I just formulated a set for a problem, and I'm thinking it may cause set-theoretic problems because it is based on an iterative definition:

$$X=\{a\}\cup\{f_i(x)|x\in X,i=1,..,n \}$$

Intuitively, I'm adding one element $a$ to the set $X$, and then saying: for every $x$ in $X$, $f_i(x)$ (for a finite number of $i$) is also in $X$. **Does this cause set-theoretic problems?**

Comment: Better to say something like $X_n = \{a\} \cup \{ f_i(x) \mid x\in X_{n-1}, i=1,\dotsc,n-1\}$, then take the union over all $n$.  (That seems to be what you are doing, at any rate).  The definition you give doesn't make sense to me.

Comment: Or even better: $X_n = \bigcup_{i = 1}^{n-1} f_i( X_{n-1} \cup \{a\})$.

Comment: If you are asking does there exist $\{f_i\}, X$ such that $X = \{\alpha\} \cup \{f_i(x) \mid x \in X\}$, then the answer is yes. Take $X = \{\alpha\}, f_i = \operatorname{id}_X$.

Comment: @AlexVong That's most certainly not what OP is asking.

Comment: @StefanMesken OK

Comment: @StefanMesken, indeed not.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, the set you want to exist doesn't cause any problems, but the notation that you (mis-)used would indeed raise an eyebrow. Here is an alternative representation of $X$:

Let $X_0 := \{a\}$ and for every $m \in \mathbb N$ let 
$$X_{m+1} := \{ f_i(x) \mid x \in X_m \wedge i = 1, \ldots, n \}.$$

It's easy to see that $X = \bigcup_{m \in \mathbb N} X_m$.

Comment: Thank you. I understand your notation, but why would my notation "raise an eyebrow"? Is it ill-defined, or somehow problematic? It seems at first sight to me that it is the same as your notation.

Comment: With your approach, it's not clear that such an $X$ exists. In fact, your 'construction' of $X$ assumes that $X$ already exists. Once we have $X$, the formula in your post in indeed satisfied.

Comment: BTW I’d rather write $i\in\{1,\ldots,n\}$ instead of @Programmer2134’s original $i = 1,\ldots,n$, as the latter is somewhat too informal and possibly syntactically ambiguous (not here, but in general) to look right inside a formula, and not as a side note. :)

Comment: @arseniiv I don't think that I agree: Let $\mathcal M$ be your favorite model that doesn't know anything about set theory. Let $f_i$, for $i = 1, \ldots, n$, be an $\mathcal M$-definable function. Let $Y = \{ y \in | \mathcal M | \mid \mathcal M \models \exists x \colon f_1(x) = y \vee \ldots \vee f_n(x) = y \}$. This set is clearly $\mathcal M$-definable even if $\{1, \ldots, n \} \not \in \mathcal M$. And from my point of view, this sort of syntactical composition is what we use to construct $X$ - it's a feature of the language, not of set theory.

Comment: @arseniiv This fine difference becomes much more apparent if we assume that our underlying universe has non-standard natural numbers. Clearly you would want that $i = 1, \ldots, n$ allows for only finitely many values for $i$, wouldn't you?

Comment: @StefanMesken, What do you mean by a "model" $\mathcal M$, and what does it mean for a function to be "$\mathcal M$-definable"?

Comment: By model I mean model of some first order language in the sense of [model theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model_theory) but that's not relevant to your question. The entire question whether to write $i = 1, \ldots, n$ or $i \in \{ 1, \ldots, n \}$ shouldn't worry you - but there is a fine difference in its meaning that becomes important if one talks about infinite sequences.

Comment: @StefanMesken Oh, I misread a bit from the start, too. I’d write the formula in full (and in full generality :) as $X_{m+1} = \{y\mid \exists x\in X_m.\,\exists i\in I.\, y = f_i(x)\}$, or, equivalently, $\bigcup_{i\in I}\{f_i(x)\mid x\in X_m\}$. Here $I$ is any set, and $f$ is an $I$-indexed sequence of functions. *If* one wants some concrete finite $|I|$, say, 3, then there’s simply no place for nonstandard naturals to emerge: predicate $i\in \{n\mid n\in\mathbb N\wedge n<3\}$ should in any model of ZF be true on exactly three elements of the domain. Do I miss something? (cont.)

Comment: (cont.) Else it depends on a definition of *n* somewhere earlier, which we don’t have here anyway, so if it fails to be a standard natural, it’s definer’s problem. :) (Though, I still think I missed your point.)

Comment: @arseniiv I'm not saying that your approach is invalid - I'm merely emphasizing that, in my answer, I used $n$ in its metamathematical interpretation as a natural number and the 'indexing' of the $f_i$'s as a shorthand for an expression in our first order language - not as a function $i \mapsto f_i$.

Comment: @StefanMesken Ah, thanks, now it’s completely clear! Then I’d written this as $\{y\mid x\in X_m\wedge(y = f_1(x)\vee\ldots\vee y = f_n(x))\}$. In your answer’s formula, $\wedge$ confused me earlier.

Comment: @arseniiv Oh, now I see why you'd think my formulation might be ambiguous. In any case, what you've spelled out is exactly the formulation I had in mind but I decided to adapt it to OP's notation since I didn't see the need to be overly pedantic and thought it might be easier for them to read.

Comment: @StefanMesken, getting back to your earlier comment "With your approach, it's not clear that such an $X$ exists. In fact, your 'construction' of $X$ assumes that $X$ already exists. Once we have $X$, the formula in your post in indeed satisfied."

I can interpret your statement in one of two ways: (1) your (Stefan's) formula uniquely determines $X$ and the elements in my set are also in yours, or (2) it is at first unclear whether my formula uniquely satisfies a set, but as soon as we know that your formula does, we know that my formula does too (and hence can use my formula from then on).

Comment: (2) is true. Note that a set $X$ as you describe it, is not unique. Take for example $f_i = \mathrm{id}$. Then both $\{a\}$ and $\{a,b\}$ satisfy your formula (and you can get arbitrarily many different $X$'s that do). This is another problem with your approach: Your formula doesn't uniquely define a set -- even if we knew from the beginning that some such set must exist.